# Service method specified as handler for of consumer "product_action_attribute.update" is not available?

Tags: magento2, cron

**Magento 2.4.4-p1**

After updating to Magento 2.4.4-p1 I am getting this error in my cron logs:

> Service method specified as handler for of consumer
> "product_action_attribute.update" is not available. Given
> "Magento\Catalog\Model\Attribute\Backend\Consumer::process"

Any idea how to address and fix that?

Thanks!